# Distribute values based on count of string in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to distribute the payments based on the states as follows:

payment:

```
  cust_id    name       date  amount
0       A  Edward 2021-01-01    3000
1       B   Henry 2021-01-01    5000
2       C   Ferth 2021-02-01    1000
```

state:

```
  cust_id  contract_id   state1    state2    state3
0       A            1  Alabama    Alaska   Arizona
1       A            2  Indiana   Alabama  Nebraska
2       B            3  Alabama       NaN   Arizona
3       C            4   Alaska  Nebraska       NaN
4       C            5      NaN     Maine  Nebraska
```

The customer may have at least one contract and each contract covers different states. Each state must be counted and those that occur twice will be counted twice in the computation of the ratio and so on. The ratio will then be multiplied by the amount to get the allocated amount per state.

Output:

```
cust_id    name       date     state     ratio  amount
0       A  Edward 2021-01-01   Alabama  0.333333    1000
1       A  Edward 2021-01-01    Alaska  0.166667     500
2       A  Edward 2021-01-01   Arizona  0.166667     500
3       A  Edward 2021-01-01   Indiana  0.166667     500
4       A  Edward 2021-01-01  Nebraska  0.166667     500
5       B   Henry 2021-01-01   Alabama  0.500000    2500
6       B   Henry 2021-01-01   Arizona  0.500000    2500
7       C   Ferth 2021-02-01    Alaska  0.250000     250
8       C   Ferth 2021-02-01  Nebraska  0.500000     500
9       C   Ferth 2021-02-01     Maine  0.250000     250
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using `df.melt` followed by `df.groupby` and `value_counts` with `normalize=True` so that we can flatten the states for each customer and based on the no of appearances, we get the pct share of each state. Then merge with the payments dataframe and finally multiply the `amount` with the pct share to get the new amount:

**Solution:**

```
u = (state.melt(['cust_id','contract_id'],value_name='state')
    .groupby("cust_id")['state'].value_counts(normalize=True)
    .reset_index(name='ratio'))

out = payment.merge(u,on='cust_id')
out['new_amount'] = out['amount']*out['ratio']
```

---

**Output:**

```
print(out)

  cust_id    name        date  amount     state     ratio  new_amount
0       A  Edward  2021-01-01    3000   Alabama  0.333333      1000.0
1       A  Edward  2021-01-01    3000    Alaska  0.166667       500.0
2       A  Edward  2021-01-01    3000   Arizona  0.166667       500.0
3       A  Edward  2021-01-01    3000   Indiana  0.166667       500.0
4       A  Edward  2021-01-01    3000  Nebraska  0.166667       500.0
5       B   Henry  2021-01-01    5000   Alabama  0.500000      2500.0
6       B   Henry  2021-01-01    5000   Arizona  0.500000      2500.0
7       C   Ferth  2021-02-01    1000    Alaska  0.250000       250.0
8       C   Ferth  2021-02-01    1000     Maine  0.250000       250.0
9       C   Ferth  2021-02-01    1000  Nebraska  0.500000       500.0
```